Is this ringing?
I'm in the process of setting up input shaping on Marlin 2.1.2.4 on my Ender 3 Neo.
I'm following the Teaching Tech tutorial on YouTube and I don't see the same ringing on my print as he does. On mine it looks like it's temporarily under-extruding, but why? The rest of  the walls look clean to me.
I'm using his acceleration calibration tool
Teaching Tech's print:

My print (basic PLA at 200 deg C):

Here are the acceleration settings for the above

